# Bilinear pairing for compact BLS signature

Tags: pairings, bls-signature, domain-parameters

What family of bilinear pairing is recommendable for BLS signature when the overriding criteria is compactness of the signature, as desirable for something to be keyed-in from printout, or embedded in a small QR-code?

Is there something giving signature size lower than ≈384 bit for 128-bit conjectured security, as in this [draft RFC](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-bls-signature-05.html#name-comparison-with-ecdsa), which is no more compact than a more conservative and faster [short Schnorr signature](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00196725)?

What's the current status of Barreto/Naehrig curves (*Pairing-Friendly Elliptic Curves of Prime Order*, in [proceedings of SAC 2005](https://doi.org/10.1007/11693383_22) and [eprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/133))?

Assuming that's no longer in use: any info about what Paulo S. L. M. Barreto [reported](http://sac2013.irmacs.sfu.ca/slides/s1.pdf#page=8) has been successfully used for VAT receipt purposes in the province of São Paulo (Brazil) 2008-2013, with 160-bit signatures of security then conjectured roughly equivalent to RSA-1024?

[image: Brazil 2008 VAT receipt]

Comment: Can't answer the other parts, but BN curves are not really used anymore because of the Number Field Sieve (https://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/kim-barbulescu-variant-of-the-number-field-sieve-to-compute-discrete-logarithms-in-finite-fields/). For the same security level, BLS curves are faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the landscape has changed much since 2019, but looking at the paper  [A taxonomy of pairings, their security, their complexity](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/485.pdf) by Barbulescu et al we want a pairing-friendly curve with 128-bits of security and the smallest possible $q$. The best option seems to be in table 11 using the cubic twist variant of BLS coined `k27method66` by Zhang and Lin in their paper [Analysis of optimum pairing products at high security levels](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-34931-7_24) where a 300-bit $q$ is possible (the pairing landing in the field $q^{27}$).

For Barreto-Naehrig curves at the 128-bit security level, Barbuescu et el suggest a base prime $q$ of 462 bits.

ETA: To be explicit about the `k27method66` curve with 300-bit prime, the recipe (per section 5.4 of the Barbulescu paper) is to choose a 15-bit $u$ and set
$$q=(u-1)^2(u^{18}+u^9+1)/3+u$$
$$r=(u^{18}+u^9+1/)3$$
then if $q$ is prime, with these choice a curve with complex multiplication with discriminant 3 over $\mathbb F_q$ will have group size divisible by $r$ and $r$ will divide $q^{27}-1$ which fits the criteria for a pairing taking values in $\mathbb F_{q^{27}}$.
In the table we see to take $u=2^{15}-2^{10}+2^3+1$ and a little `sage`:

```
u = 2^15-2^10+2^3+1
q = (u-1)^2*(u^18+u^9+1)//3+u
print(q.is_prime())
print(q)
E = EllipticCurve(GF(q),[0,-2])
r = (u^18+u^9+1)//3
print(r.is_prime())
print(r)
print((q^27-1)%r)
print(E.cardinality()%r)
```

produces

```
True
```

`361865065320728439833719086758866208857114634221052000919029745553653612029141017881951817`

```
True
```

`358925642337106139753780938745883044679182292122981674007816040062299252055237641`

```
0
0
```

Telling us that the curve $y^2=x^3-2$ admits a pairing from $E(\mathbb F_q)\times\mathbf E(\mathbb F_{q^{27}})\to \mathbf F_{q^{27}}^\times$. Picking points $P_1$ and $P_2$ of order $r$ from the two curve groups should give generators for a non-degenerate pairing. A private key $s$ can produce public key $sP_2$ and signatures $sH$ where $H$ is a hash of the message to a point in $\langle P_1\rangle$. Note that using point compression we should be able to represent $sH$ in 299 bits ($q$ is actually only 298 bits long). Signature can be checked by the pairing relationship $e(H,sP_2)=e(sH,P_2)$.

Comment: I see the [table 11](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/485.pdf#table.caption.27), about method 6.6 at 128-bit security, and the line $k=27$ with $\log_2q=300$. But I fail to link that with Barbulescu's data [k27method66.txt](https://razvanbarbulescu.pages.math.cnrs.fr/Pairings/k27method66.txt) and [k27method66-128-3.txt](https://plmlab.math.cnrs.fr/razvanbarbulescu/razvanbarbulescu.pages.math.cnrs.fr/-/blob/fe5a092e263636af2d95090e82bc2dc51977f6f9/save-bdq/d-k27method66-128-3.txt). And much more to grasp what signing and checking the corresponding 300-bit BLS signature would involve.

Comment: @fgrieu I've tried to expand on the construction. The costing files don't seem to include this case as they aim to get 175-bits of security for the multiplicative discrete logarithm problem for some reason.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm a step closer to understanding how signing and verifying would work. And at least I grasp that the arithmetic in $\mathbb F_{q^{27}}$ is going to require non-trivial work. I deffer accepting the answer until I study that more. I'm trying to iron out how much of [draft-irtf-cfrg-bls-signature-05](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/pdf/draft-irtf-cfrg-bls-signature-05) and [draft-irtf-cfrg-pairing-friendly-curves-11](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-pairing-friendly-curves-11) apply, and why something from k27method66 is not included there.

Comment: I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.11920.pdf#page=15) which I hope is somewhat relevant. They do consider $k=27$ but only starting at the 192-bit security level, and I do not get why. For now this is all flying at high altitude above my head, including their appendix B on arithmetic in $\mathbb F_{p^{27}}$; I do not even get if the math in that appendix is compatible or antagonist with what I think is the reference for [method 6.6](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/372.pdf#page=28), subcase of $k≡9\pmod{18}$!

Comment: Happy to explain some of that paper [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144304/pairings-for-bls-signatures)